# drag and drop editable email template

Tags: jquery-ui-draggable, email-templates

I am using Jquery UI for making a editable email template but on rearranging my divs position is set to absolute which is not working there in gmail. if there is an alternate way then please suggest.

Comment: Did you try in https://ux.stackexchange.com/?

Answer (score 2):

Absolute positioning does not work in Gmail, Outlook, Yahoo as well. You don't post a code example, so it's difficult to determine what you're doing and make a suggestion.

Email development is not front-end development. They have different rules. Things like JavaScript or jQuery will never work.

Campaign Monitor has an excellent guide to what CSS elements work in email.

- https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/
- https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/positioning-display/position/

Good luck.